# Загрузка файла в корень сайта из скрипта, который находится за пределами корня

Tags: php

Добрый вечер, есть файл который загружает картинки в папку, которая находится в корне сайта, а сам файл-загрузчик находится за пределами корня, из за этого не загружаются файлы, подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему

Comment: «пределами корня» — это выше или ниже? Можно пример с абс. путями?

Если речь об `open_basedir`, то, насколько я знаю, обойти это не получится, остается только php.ini ковырять.

Comment: Архитектура:
aplictation/upload.php
-----
suite.com/images - Сюда нужно загрузить
---
ещё папки

Comment: на папке сайта лежит индексный файл, в нём подключается загрузчик

Comment: а в чём проблема ?

Comment: не загружает в папку картинку

Comment: проверьте права на директорию, покажите кусок кода, которым вы это делаете, может у вас какая-то другая проблема, распечатайте ошибки.

Comment: Проверьте в файле «загрузчика» `getcwd()`. Наверное, в путях просто запутался.

Comment: Права 777, напрямую через индексный файл создал в папку файл, всё ок. функция вернула:/var/www/admin/data/www/мойсайт

Comment: а я понял, ваша проблема в том, что вы называете диркторию в *nix папкой, сразу -20 к скиллу работы с файловой системой. 

----

а если серьезно - а в какой путь (напечатайте его) у вас файл складывается ?

Comment: То есть, index.php лежит в

    /var/www/admin/data/www/suite.com/index.php

Загрузчик в

    /var/www/admin/data/www/upload.php

А залить нужно в

    /var/www/admin/data/www/suite.com/images/

Верно? И файл пишется так:

    file_put_contents('./images/file.ext', '[data]');

несмотря на то что хочется написать `'./suite.com/images/file.ext'`?

Если так, то код в студию!